# AttributeError: 'Pool' object has no attribute '__exit__'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing, python-3.2, python-3.1

I'm doing some multiprocessing python scripts using `multiprocessing.Pool`. These scripts look like the following:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:         # start 4 worker processes
        print(pool.map(f, range(10)))       # prints "[0, 1, 4,..., 81]"
```

When running this with Python 3.4, everything is fine. However, when using Python **2.6** or **3.1** I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Pool' object has no attribute '__exit__'
```

Using Python **2.7** or **3.2**, the error is essentially the same:

```
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Why does this happen and how can I circumvent this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) says that `multiprocessing.pool` supports the context management protocol (`with` statements) in Python version **3.3** and above.

> New in version 3.3: Pool objects now support the context management protocol – see Context Manager Types. `__enter__()` returns the pool object, and `__exit__()` calls `terminate()`.

So you either need a **newer version of Python**, or use one of the two following possibilities **changing your code** (tested with Python versions 2.6, 2.7, 3.1, 3.2):

1. rewrite your code like this to eliminate the `with` statement:

   ```
   from multiprocessing import Pool

   def f(x):
       return x*x

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       pool = Pool(processes=4)            # start 4 worker processes
       print(pool.map(f, range(10)))       # prints "[0, 1, 4,..., 81]"
       pool.terminate()
   ```
2. as pointed out in the comments, use `contextlib.closing()`:

   ```
   from multiprocessing import Pool
   import contextlib

   def f(x):
       return x*x

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       with contextlib.closing(Pool(processes=4)) as pool:
           print(pool.map(f, range(10)))
   ```

Comment: what will be solution for python 2.7 ?

Comment: @AshishKarpe: Both code examples also work with Python 2.7. Do you get an error message?

Comment: @user1231007  error same as mentioned above : AttributeError: 'Pool' object has no attribute '__exit__'

Comment: @AshishKarpe that's weird - I just tested both examples on two machines with Python 2.6 and Python 2.7 - no error message