# How to parallelize this nested loop in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested-loops, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to improve the performance of my code and can't figure out how to implement multiprocessing module in it.

I am using linux (CentOS 7.2) and python 2.7

The code that I need to run in a parallel environment:

```
def start_fetching(directory):
    with open("test.txt", "a") as myfile:
        try:
            for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
                for current_file in filenames:
                    current_file = dirpath + "/" + current_file
                    myfile.write(current_file)
            return 0
        except:
            return sys.exc_info()[0]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cwd = "/home/"
    final_status = start_fetching(cwd)
    exit(final_status)
```

I need to save the meta-data of all the files (here, only filename is shown) in a database. Here I am only storing the file name in a text file.

Comment: You just create a new `Thread` for each time you do something inside the second `for` loop. Same as usual. https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614584/parallel-directory-walk-python) might help!

Comment: Trying to append to a file from multiple threads simultaneously is not generally a good idea.

Comment: @AndreyShipilov Thanks, I'll try that and see if it helps.

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran This post seems really helpful, It completely matches my scenario. Will try and let you know.

Comment: Just a comment. The performance is likely bound by how fast you can `write()`.  Depending on the nature of the I/O media and file system, parallelism may or may not help.  It could make things worse.

Comment: @jknupp I was thinking to make multiple files and append data in them simultaneously using multiple processes, And then in the end append all those files into one.

Comment: @CongMa I understand that, But I thought if I have a 4 core processor, then 4 processes can parallelly append 4 text files. Wouldn't that improve the performance?

Comment: The bottleneck isn't likely CPU-bound. This is an I/O-bound task.

Comment: @CongMa But what if this script is run on a high performance system, wouldn't the multiprocessing help there? [I am planning to run this script on large HPC clusters]

Comment: You can try to find it out, since it depends on your system's configuration. But based on your description you're writing to a database.  Here the database is almost always the bottleneck (unless it's in-memory).  You can try parallelize the writing but that doesn't mean the database can scale up and handle the contention.  Running it on a "HPC cluster" doesn't necessarily mean parallelism should be always faster.

Comment: @CongMa I agree that database would be a bottleneck, that's why I was thinking to store the data in a file first and then later on (on a different system where I can compromise with time), use a separate script to implement it in a database. And yes the performance would greatly depend on the system I would run this on, that's why I was thinking to make this as generic as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for helping me reduce this script's processing time to almost half. (I am adding this as an answer as I can't add this much content in a comment)

I found two ways to achieve what I wished for:

1. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614584/parallel-directory-walk-python) link mentioned by @KeerthanaPrabhakaran, Which is concerned with the multi-threading.

   ```
   def worker(filename):
       subprocess_out = subprocess.Popen(["stat", "-c",
                                  "INSERT INTO file VALUES (NULL, \"%n\", '%F', %s, %u, %g, datetime(%X, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'), datetime(%Y, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'), datetime(%Z, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'));", filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
       return subprocess_out.communicate()[0]

   def start_fetching(directory, threads):
       filename = fetch_filename() + ".txt"
       with contextlib.closing(multiprocessing.Pool(threads)) as pool:   # pool of threads processes
           with open(filename, "a") as myfile:
               walk = os.walk(directory)
               fn_gen = itertools.chain.from_iterable((os.path.join(root, file) for file in files) for root, dirs, files in walk)

               results_of_work = pool.map(worker, fn_gen)  # this does the parallel processing
               print "Concatenating the result into the text file"
               for result in results_of_work:
                   myfile.write(str(result))
       return filename
   ```

   ***This is traversing 15203 files in 0m15.154s.***
2. The Second one, That @ArunKumar mentioned, was related to multiprocessing:

   ```
   def task(filename, process_no, return_dict):
       subprocess_out = subprocess.Popen(["stat", "-c",
                                  "INSERT INTO file VALUES (NULL, \"%n\", '%F', %s, %u, %g, datetime(%X, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'), datetime(%Y, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'), datetime(%Z, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'));",
                                  filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
       return_dict[process_no] = subprocess_out.communicate()[0]


   def start_fetching_1(directory):
       try:
           processes = []
           i = 0
           manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
           return_dict = manager.dict()

           for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
               for current_file in filenames:
                   current_file = dirpath + "/" + current_file
                   # Create Seperate process and do what you want, becausee Multi-threading wont help in parallezing
                   p = multiprocessing.Process(target=task, args=(current_file, i, return_dict))
                   i += 1
                   p.start()
                   processes.append(p)

           # Let all the child processes finish and do some post processing if needed.
           for process in processes:
               process.join()

           with open("test.txt", "a") as myfile:
               myfile.write(return_dict.values())

           return 0
       except:
           return sys.exc_info()[0]
   ```

   ***This is traversing 15203 files in 1m12.197s***

I don't understand why multiprocessing is taking that much time (**my initial code was taking 0m27.884s only**), but utilizing almost 100% CPU.

The above Codes are exact codes that I am running, (I am storing these info in a file and than use these test.txt file to create database entries)

I am trying to optimize the above code further, but can't think of a better way, as @CongMa mentioned, it might have finally come to the I/O bottleneck.

Comment: To summarize - for traversing 15203 files: sequential impl took 0m27.884s, multi-threading took 0m15.154s and multi-process took 1m12.197s.
It is logical multi-threading performed better than sequential coz the task has lot of I/O.
And the multi-process didn't perform well coz of the no.of processes created (15203 files). Since, we created 1 process for every file and assigned a separate task. Creation of process is really costly and 15K process is really huge and CPU will be chocked to schedule among these processes. While it is not the same with creation of threads.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. And I am planning to run this script on a much much larger number of files (x10^4 times). Do you think it will be stable at that level?

Comment: Multi-process should not be the approach for such big scale of parallelism. It will benefit of the number is <= no.of actual physical cores. Not sure multi-thread will also have benefits because of resource contention. Anyway its good to experiment the multi-thread and sequential thing.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want have parallelize tasks which are big. whatever you have give is just the filename into a file.
I h have created a separate file for every thread output and later you can combine all these files as well. There are other-ways to achieve this.

If the main problem is parallelizing, below could be a solution.

Python supports multi-threading and multi-processing. Multi-threading is not truly parallel processing, in case of IO blocks we can have parallel executions. If you want code in parallel, use multi-processing[https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html]. You code may look something like below.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def task(filename):
    with open(filename+"test.txt", "a") as myfile:
         myfile.write(filename)

def start_fetching(directory):
    try:
        processes = []
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
            for current_file in filenames:
                current_file = dirpath + "/" + current_file
                # Create Seperate process and do what you want, becausee Multi-threading wont help in parallezing
                p = Process(target=f, args=(current_file,))
                p.start()
                processes.append(p)

        # Let all the child processes finish and do some post processing if needed.
        for process in processes:
            process.join()

        return 0
    except:
        return sys.exc_info()[0] 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cwd = "/home/"
    final_status = start_fetching(cwd)
    exit(final_status)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: you start a process then instantly wait it to finish, nothing is running parallelized here.

Comment: that looks much better

Comment: Thank you @ArunKumar, Please check the answer I just posted.